# Add UIButton below UIPageIndicator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uipagecontrol

I'm building the tutorial section of an iOS app. I have three pages in the tutorial, and I've correctly set up the `UIPageIndicators` for each page.
What I need is to put a `UIButton` below the `UIPageIndicators` and an image at the background. I have attached the design image also so that you understand what I mean.[image: image description]

Any ideas about that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: create the UIVIew into the Pagecontroller as you want in size and set background image of UIPageview. and for the button you have to set UIButtton in second UIVIew which is subview of main VC. and add it those UIVIew at the bottom of your VC. after PageController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i have implement same thing in my project and it's working fine for me.

controller.h---->   

 @interface FastTickIntroScreen : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>
    {
        IBOutlet UIButton *btnStartMessgaing;
        IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrViewForIntro;
        IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;

        NSMutableArray *arrImages;

        NSInteger pos;
        NSInteger posScr;


        //    IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;


    }
    - (IBAction)btnStartMessgaingTapped:(id)sender;


    controller.m---->

@implementation FastTickIntroScreen
{
    CGFloat lastContentOffset;
}

#pragma mark-
#pragma mark- UIbuttion Action Method


-(void)viewDidLoad{

    arrImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1FastTick"],
               [UIImage imageNamed:@"2Chat"],
               [UIImage imageNamed:@"3Video"],
               [UIImage imageNamed:@"4Nearby"],
               [UIImage imageNamed:@"5Discover"], nil];

    NSArray *arrTitle=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"Real time texting",@"Instant video messaging",@"Nearby",@"Discover", nil];

    pos=0;

    posScr=0;
    scrViewForIntro.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrViewForIntro.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrViewForIntro.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    [scrViewForIntro setDelegate:self];
    scrViewForIntro.contentSize=CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width*arrImages.count, 50);

    UILabel *lbl;
    UIImageView*imgViewForIntro;

    for (int i=0; i<arrImages.count; i++) {

        imgViewForIntro=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(pos, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                                     self.view.frame.size.height)];
        [imgViewForIntro setImage:[arrImages objectAtIndex:i]];
        [scrViewForIntro addSubview:imgViewForIntro];

        lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(pos, self.view.frame.size.height-130, self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                       30)];
        [lbl setText:[arrTitle objectAtIndex:i]];
        [lbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [lbl setFont:KSetFont(kDefaultFontName, 20)];
        [lbl setBackgroundColor:CLEARCOLOUR];
        [scrViewForIntro addSubview:lbl];

        pos = pos+self.view.frame.size.width;
        imgViewForIntro.tag=i;
    }

    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    pageControl.numberOfPages = 5;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
}

- (IBAction)btnStartMessgaingTapped:(id)sender {

//    Congratulations *objScreen=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Congratulations"];
//    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objScreen animated:YES];

    if(posScr<arrImages.count){
        posScr +=1;
        [scrViewForIntro scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(posScr*scrViewForIntro.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"Position: %li",(long)posScr);
        NSInteger pageNumber = roundf(scrViewForIntro.contentOffset.x / (scrViewForIntro.frame.size.width));
        pageControl.currentPage = pageNumber+=1;

        if (pageNumber == 5){
            TermsAndCondScreen *objScreen=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TermsAndCondScreen"];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:objScreen animated:YES];
            posScr--;
        }
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.x)
    {
        CGFloat width = scrollView.frame.size.width;
        NSInteger page = (scrollView.contentOffset.x + (0.5f * width)) / width;
        posScr=page;
    }
    else if (lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.x)
    {
        CGFloat width = scrollView.frame.size.width;
        NSInteger page = (scrollView.contentOffset.x + (0.5f * width)) / width;
        posScr=page;
    }
    lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;

}

- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender {
    CGFloat x = pageControl.currentPage * scrViewForIntro.frame.size.width;
    [scrViewForIntro setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, 0) animated:YES];
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView  {
    NSInteger pageNumber = roundf(scrViewForIntro.contentOffset.x / (scrollView.frame.size.width));
    pageControl.currentPage = pageNumber;
}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1):

What problem you are facing with?

You can use custom page controller and add some constraints to it. That way, you will have much more control of the items.

Comment: At first didn't really know where to put my button and page indicators so that they remain stable in the UI. So I created a custom view controller, added the page control and my uibutton in there with their constraints, added the scroll view as needed and feed the scroll view with a separate page item controller, where I implemented the "container" design of each page.